# Get encoding of audio track

Tags: c++, audio, encoding, metadata, type-signature

Suppose I have .3g2 file. I noticed, they can contain audio track of different encoding (AAC, AMR).

Or, for example, an .m4a file can contain (AAC or ALAC) encoded audio track.

[MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) detects it pretty well, but I want to be able to do that using C++.

My question is, how can I detect the type of the audio track in a media file?

Thanks.

Comment: C++ - all by yourself or using existing C/C++ libraries? Using FFMPEG library sounds like a good option.

Comment: "Mobile phones use 3GP, an implementation of MPEG-4 Part 12 (a.k.a. MPEG-4/JPEG2000 ISO Base Media file format), similar to MP4. It uses .3gp and .3g2 extensions"  so if your life depended on it you can read up on its ISO spec in pdf file listed at http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/index.html  with direct pdf file at http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/c068960_ISO_IEC_14496-12_2015.zip     I once did a project where the clincher uber low level parse spec was only available from such an ISO spec good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/MediaInfo) is also available with a C++ interface, just download MediaInfo library package, and [here is a C++ example](https://github.com/MediaArea/MediaInfoLib/blob/master/Source/Example/HowToUse.cpp).

For getting the first audio track format: `MediaInfo::Get(Stream_Audio, 0, "Format")`